# MGF bound for non-centered random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds, moment-generating-functions, concentration-of-measure

So I was trying to prove the following fact: if $|X| \leq 1$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$, then $\mathbb{E} e^{t (X - \mu)} \leq e^{t^2/2}$, for any real $t$.

I can show this in the special case $\mu = 0$:
for $x \in [-1, 1]$ we note by convexity
$$
e^{tx} \leq \frac{1-x}{2} e^{-t} + \frac{1 + x}{2} e^{t}. 
$$
Hence, taking expectations: $\mathbb{E} e^{t (X -\mu)} \leq \cosh(t) \leq e^{t^2/2}$.

Any ideas how to extend this argument to general $\mu$?

Comment: My argument does use $\mu = 0$.

Comment: Yes, it does. Withdrawn.

Comment: I suppose the convexity argument does give $$\mathbb{E}e^{t(X-\mu)}=\leq e^{-\mu t}[\cosh t-\mu \sinh t]$$ but this seems too weak to do much good. One other thought: If you rearrange to $\mathbb{E}[e^{t(X-\mu)}-1]\leq e^{t^2/2}-1$ and expand in powers of $t$, this becomes $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\mathbb{E}(X-\mu)^k \frac{t^k}{k!}\leq \frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{8}+\cdots$$
which seems suggestive. In particular, dividing by $t^2/2$ and taking the $t\to 0$ limit yields the simpler inequality $\mathbb{E}(X-\mu)^2\leq 1$.

Comment: And in fact that inequality is true (since the variance of an r.v on $[a, b]$ is bounded by $(b-a)^2/4$).

Comment: Is it possible to show $e^{-\mu t}[\cosh(t) - \mu \sinh t] \leq e^{t^2/2}$ for all $\mu \in [-1, 1]$?---I suspect not as I believe it is important that $\mu = \mathbf{E}[X]$, for example by considering point masses.

Comment: are you familiar with the tilting of r.v.'s (via MGF in denominator) as is done e.g. in random walks and importance sampling?  If not the technique I have in mind will probably be viewed as too technical.  On the other hand, if you are familiar then it's a very simple and intuitive way to prove this.

Comment: You're referring to moving from essentially $dP(x)$ to $e^{\lambda x} dP(x)$.

Comment: yes -- with the MGF in the denominator on the RHS so that it integrates to 1.  I didn't get a notification of reply -- maybe because I wasn't tagged and others have replied to this original post.  If you are familiar with the analytically treating titled r.v.'s as r.v.'s then this leads to a very simple proof.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to show that for a random variable $Y \in [a,b]$ with $\mathbb E Y =0$, we have that $\mathbb E e^{tY} \leq e^{t^2(b-a)^2/8}$. Why? Let $Y = X - \mu$, then $\mathbb E Y = 0$, $b = 1 - \mu$, $a = -1 - \mu$, $(b-a)^2 = 4$, and the bound becomes $e^{t^2/2}$.

We use the same argument as you outlined. Fix a $t$. Using the convexity of $e^{ty}$, for any $y \in [a,b]$:
\begin{aligned}
e^{ty} \leq \frac{b-y}{b-a} e^{ta} + \frac{y-a}{b-a} e^{tb}.
\end{aligned}
Therefore, using the linearity of expectation and $\mathbb E Y = 0$, we get
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb E e^{tY} \leq \frac{be^{ta} - ae^{tb}}{b-a}  =: \varphi(t).
\end{aligned}
Make the following substitution: Let $\phi(t):= \log \varphi(\frac{t}{b-a})$ and $p = -a/(b-a)$.  We need to show that $\phi(t) \leq t^2/8$.
We have that $\phi(t) = -tp + \log(1 - p + pe^{t})$.

Notice that $\phi(0) = 0$, $\phi'(0) = 0$, and
\begin{aligned}\phi''(t) = \frac{(1-p)(pe^t)}{(1-p+pe^t)^2} \leq \frac{1}{4} ,\end{aligned}
where the last inequality holds for all $t$ by the AM-GM inequality.
Applying Taylor's theorem, we get that $\phi(t) \leq t^2/8$.

**Remark**: This is a very famous result called Hoeffding's Lemma. I followed the proof given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma) as it was the closet to your original approach. For alternate proofs, see, for example, Lemma 2.2 in the book [Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199535255.001.0001/acprof-9780199535255)
.

Comment: I'm aware of this proof and the more general statement. I was hoping to see something that wasn't so technical. In the special case I highlighted above, it is a one-liner.